# Does successive calls to a method like Count() reenumerate an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm a bit confused with the IEnumerable and it's deferred execution behaviour.

Let's say I have the following `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> enumerable = GetFoos();
```

What happens if I do:

```
int count = enumerable.Count();
count = enumerable.Count();
```

I can think of three possibilities:

a) will enumerate the collection again

b) will cache the result to use on the second time (like lazy loading)

c) will depend on the underlining type instantiated in `GetFoos()` method and how it implemented the IEnumerable interface

Which one is the correct one? Also, if `c` is the correct one, what happens with an IEnumerable created using `yield return`?

Comment: The answer is (c). It would depend on the actual implementation of the collection. Some would re-enumerate, some wouldn't, some don't enumerate at all for `.Count()`, some would produce an error from attempting to enumerate multiple times.

Comment: First port of call should be the [*documentation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks): "If the type of source implements `ICollection<T>`, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check on [referencesourcecode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b,references) gives following definition for the `.Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T>)` extension (simplified):

**Disclaimer** you should *not* depend on that implementation nor expect that the implementation will always do something in a certain way.

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

So the answer it is *(c)*, it will depend on the underlying type. And if it's not of type `ICollection` the `IEnumerable` will be evaluated a second time (i.e `GetEnumerator` will be called and the Enumerator will be looped.

So what happens when using `yield` syntax?
Well `yield` is just a fancy way to implement `GetEnumerator`, so what will happen when calling `Count()` twice is that this pseudo `GetEnumerator` method will be called twice. I think a code snippet says more than a thousand words:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> ConstantEnumerable()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
}

private static int i = 0;
private static IEnumerable<int> ChangingEnumerable()
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        yield return 1;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var constant = ConstantEnumerable();
    var changing = ChangingEnumerable();
    Console.WriteLine("Constant: {0}, {1}", constant.Count(), constant.Count());  // 3, 3
    Console.WriteLine("Changing: {0}, {1}", changing.Count(), changing.Count()); // 1, 2
}
```

Comment: So if one is not aware of that and is doing heavy stuff on a yield returned method, it would result in slowness and even possible side effects by calling the method twice?

Comment: Even if `ICollection<T>` is implemented, still it depends on underlying type. Its not necessary that Count property is still not enumerated. There's no guarantee that value is Cached

Comment: @Guilherme 1. The side effect example was more for demonstration purposes. IMHO you should never ever do side effects like that in an Iterator. 2. I think it's better to optimize when needed and avoid premature optimization.